# Pretty Photo load image via ajax frame

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, prettyphoto

I have an angular app that will display some images. I am opening a prettyPhoto ajax window and passing the pathname to the URL. My script is loading the image fine, however, it isn't displaying the image how prettyPhoto traditionally displays a photo.

What do I need to do so it behaves like it is displaying a photo? i.e: has the fullscreen button, resizes the lightbox to the photo etc.

Is that even possible?

I am opening the lightbox via:

```
$scope.openLightbox = function()
{
  if (typeof $.prettyPhoto.open !== "function")
  {
    $.fn.prettyPhoto({
      social_tools:false,
      deeplinking: false,
      keyboard_shortcuts: false
    });
    $.prettyPhoto.open('resources/php/view/lightbox.php?ajax=true&path=' + $base64.encode($scope.currentFile));
    return;
  }
  $.prettyPhoto.open('resources/php/view/lightbox.php?ajax=true&path=' + $base64.encode($scope.currentFile));
}
```

`$scope.currentFile` would be something like: `data/39/my_image_name.jpg`

and I am parsing the PHP like so:

```
$path    = base64_decode($_GET['path']);
$finfo   = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime    = finfo_file($finfo, $path);
$mimeExt = explode('/', $mime);

if ($mimeExt[0] == 'image')
{
  echo '<img width="100%" height="100%" src="data:image/' . $mimeExt[1] . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)) . '">';
}
elseif ($mimeExt[0] == 'video')
{

}
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Like I said above, the image is displaying just fine, I just want it to be displayed with the standard prettyPhoto image behavior. I understand this may not be possible.

**EDIT**

So turns out I didn't need AJAX afterall:

```
$scope.openLightbox = function()
{
  if (typeof $.prettyPhoto.open !== "function")
  {
    $.fn.prettyPhoto({
      social_tools:false,
      deeplinking: false,
      keyboard_shortcuts: false
    });
    $.prettyPhoto.open('resources/php/view/lightbox.php?path=' + $base64.encode($scope.currentFile));
    return;
  }
  $.prettyPhoto.open('resources/php/view/lightbox.php?path=' + $base64.encode($scope.currentFile));
}
```

and finally my php which I am outputting the image directly to the browser so prettyPhoto thinks it is just loading an image

```
<?php
require("../config.php");
require("../connect.php");
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['ds_level']))
{
  $path    = base64_decode($_GET['path']);
  $finfo   = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $mime    = finfo_file($finfo, $path);
  $mimeExt = explode('/', $mime);

  if ($mimeExt[0] == 'image')
  {
    header('Content-Type: image/' . $mimeExt[1]);
    echo file_get_contents($path);
  }
  elseif ($mimeExt[0] == 'video')
  {
    //do other stuff to display video
  }
  finfo_close($finfo);
}
else
{
  //-- no access
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do I need to do so it behaves like it is displaying a photo? i.e: has the fullscreen button, resizes the lightbox to the photo etc.
>
> Is that even possible?

**Yes, it is possible**. You need to create a dedicated directive, [as specified in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/fannheyward/7560525):

```
.directive('prettyp', function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
  $("[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({deeplinking: false,    social_tools: false});
  }
})
```

To apply it, specify `rel="prettyPhoto"` in the anchor, like so:

```
<a prettyp ng-href="{{image.url}}" rel="prettyPhoto[main]" target="_blank" title="{{image.title}}">
```

---

HOW IT WORKS

The directive looks for a `rel` attribute starting with `prettyPhoto`, and applies the prettyPhoto magic to it.

---

EXAMPLE

I made a Plunk you can play around with: [**check the Plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wOKBE9?p=preview)

---

IN YOUR CODE

To apply the directive in your code, you could replace:

```
echo '<a href="data:image/' . $mimeExt[1] . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)) . '" prettyp rel="prettyPhoto[main]" target="_blank" ><img width="100%" height="100%" src="data:image/' . $mimeExt[1] . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)) . '"></a>';
```

with:

```
echo '<img width="100%" height="100%" src="data:image/' . $mimeExt[1] . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)) . '">';
```

---

EDIT AFTER CHAT SESSION

As your images are protected with `.htaccess`, you have opted to work with a base64 version of your image, and why not?

However, it seems that if you wait until the user clicks the 'view' button in your app, it takes too long to go fetch the protected image and encode it, before passing it on to prettyPhoto:

[image]

I recommend you go fetch your image *before* the user clicks the `view` button, when the user selects the image in the list.

The long process of:

1. make an ajax call to php server;
2. have php app fetch image;
3. have php app encode image;
4. have angularjs/javaScript app store the base64 string

can then be done automatically, preventively, in the background.
The user experience would then be optimised.

> So when the user does click the `view` button, the base64 version of the image can be passed to prettyPhoto straight away, without any server call: this would produce the same result as displayed in the plunkr I provided, when the button is pressed.

Comment: the problem is I don't have anchor tags to open the files. I have a file tree with a "view" button. When you have selected a file in the file tree, the user clicks the view button which programmatically calls `$.prettyPhoto.open('resources/php/view/lightbox.php?ajax=true&path=' + $base64.encode($scope.currentFile));` I have echo'd out an image tag with a width and height of 100% already and that sort of works. The prettyPhoto frame isn't resizing like opening a traditional image.

Comment: The main thing I need to do is open an image via the ajax frame and have pretty photo act like I am opening a normal image. This post may explain a little better: http://www.coralwebdesigns.com/blog/prettyphoto-live-event-with-ajax-loaded-content/ I tried the solution there but it did not work

Comment: the blog you provided a link to uses the same technique I mentioned, except the code I posted is adapted for angularjs. Can you post the code of your file tree view button, please? Did you check the plunk I made, does it achieve the desired result? It could be a button instead of an anchor tag, if you wish.

Comment: Here is a screen shot of what my UI looks like. I'll edit my post to include the full code for launching the light box. http://imgur.com/Xi3rUgl I did see the plunkr, however, your plunker assumes I know the path. My app does know the relative path, but I must output it using base64 because the images are blocked via htaccess for security reasons

Comment: thank you, your screenshot is helpful. To show an image, you must know the path, whether there is some decoding involved or not. So let's assume you know the path. If you had to put your issue in a few words, would it be: "how can I have prettyPhoto open my image when I press a button instead of an anchor link?"

Comment: @Ronnie, I made another directive, and added a button that works nicely with prettyPhoto in the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/wOKBE9?p=preview    Hoping it was what you were looking for? coding/encoding of base64 can be added in the directive, if you wish, just let me know...

Comment: I must output this image via base64 because apache blocks it via HTTP. So the pathname, even known, is not directly accessible. This is why I need an ajax frame.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78823/discussion-between-manube-and-ronnie).

Comment: I believe I have figured it out. Rather than using an AJAX frame, I have lightbox.php output an image directly using `imagecreatefromstring` and `imagejpeg` / `imagepng`. This way prettyPhoto thinks its loading just an image. An example string would be `$.prettyPhoto.open('resources/php/view/lightbox.php?path={a base64 encoded path name}`

Comment: In regards to your edit. I don't recommened fetching the images before the user clicks because in my case, these images can be quite large and can have any number of images in a given folder. That would severely tax the server if I had to preload all images. When I mentioned preload in chat, I meant a visible preloader, not actually preload the images

Comment: You would preload only the image selected by the user in the list (blue background in the picture), but before the view button is clicked

Comment: ah, I understand what you mean. So when the file is selected, it gets preloaded regardless if they hit view, right?

Comment: Yes, what do you say?

Comment: I still don't like that idea. I don't think that should be necessary to achieve what I need. I have actually made this really simple. I will edit my post above to show the solution.

Comment: Ok, glad you could fix it

Comment: I appreciate all the help, talking to you put my head in a different mind set. I'd say that is worth 100pts in itself. If anyone is interested in my solution, check the edit. Thanks @Manube